# Problems getting data in server with Instagram ?__a=1 url

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using this code to get the last 8-10 post from an account:

```
$feed_instagram = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/?__a=1');

$feed_instagram = json_decode($feed_instagram, true);
```

And it works like a charm in my development environment (local).

When I try to do the same in my staging development (AWS) it just returns a HTML with the Instagram logo.

Tried this other approach I saw on another post here:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$arr = explode('window._sharedData = ',$html);
$arr = explode(';</script>',$arr[1]);

$feed_instagram = json_decode($arr[0] , true);
```

And works locally aswell, but on the AWS environment it looks like it needs Login or something:

```
[entry_data] => Array
        (
            [LoginAndSignupPage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [captcha] => Array
                                (
                                    [enabled] => 
                                    [key] => 
                                )

                            [gdpr_required] => 1
                            [tos_version] => eu
                            [username_hint] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

Locally, in "entry_data" i get a "ProfilePage" object with all the info I need.

Any clue why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Solving this two months old question, it seems like Instagram / Facebook blocks certain services IPS (tested AWS and Digital Ocean). Since this project only needed to be running for two months, I ended up using a Raspberry Pi with a cron task.